# Finding a sequence of to the minimizer of a differentiable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, optimization

$h : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function, bounded from below. I want to find a sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that:

$$h(x_k) \to \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} h(x) $$

and

$$\nabla h(x_k) \to 0 $$

My hunch has been to simply prove the existence of a minimizer and use the completeness of the space to consider any sequence converging to the minimizer. However, I've been told to attempt this with something called Ekeland's Principle and am unable to prove it specifically using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ekeland's variational principle, for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
h(x_k) \leq \inf h + \frac{1}{k}\,,
\qquad
h(x_k) \leq h(x) + \frac{1}{k} \|x - x_k\|,
\qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,.
$$
Hence, for every $t>0$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$
\frac{h(x_k) - h(x_k + tv)}{t} \leq \frac{1}{k} \|v\|, 
$$
so that, passing to the limit as $t\to 0^+$,
$$
- \nabla h(x_k) \cdot v \leq \frac{1}{k}\|v\|.
$$
Since this inequality holds for every $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, one gets
$$
|\nabla h(x_k)| \leq \frac{1}{k}\,.
$$

Comment: On comparing your proof to the statement for Ekeland's Variational Principle on Wikipedia, can it be said that you're generating the sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ by considering each $x_k$ to be the point $v$ (in Wikipedia's terms) for when $\epsilon = \dfrac{1}{k}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.